# Hibernate spring data jba one to many bidirectional recurse loop - change json ignore depends on parent entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have one-to-many relationship. Hotel and Country. Country can have M hotels, the Hotel has one country.

**HotelEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel")
public class HotelEntity {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH},
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private CountryEntity country;

    ...
}
```

**CountryEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class CountryEntity {
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<HotelEntity> hotels;

    ...
}
```

*The ... symbolises rest of class (like other entity property, getters, setters, constructor) that have nothing in common with this problem and make this harder to read and understand*

So. In my first try, I havent used **JsonManagedReference** and **JsonBackReference** and I got the infinite recursion, stack overflow exception. And it makes sence... kinda... I loaded Country by Id using Spring data Jpa interface (the build-in method), the Country has list of Hotels (hotel has country, ... etc). These two annotations worked. Until I needed to load just a Hotel by Id. Because of there annotations, the Country was not included in the result. I understand why. But **Is there any chance to annotate the entity property not to be included** (or be included just once) **in depends on from which entity I load the other side entity?**

For example, I would like to load Hotel. With Hotel I like to serialize the Country entity, **but without list of hotels** (so Just basic informations like Name, flag image path, ...).

But in other case, for example the **Location entity** (same relation like hotels - location has one country, country has N locations) I would like to load the whole country (including the list of hotels that belong to that country).

I dont know If i described this properly, hope you understand me.

The only solution that I figured out by myself was doing my own interface method heads **with @Query** where I pick what I really want. But this solution seems to be little ugly in my opinion and I would like to ask if there is a more pretty way using Jackson and the other Hibernate annotations.

Comment: Entities represent your persistence model. What is saved in the database. What is manipulated by your business logic. Your communication model (i.e. what is returned or accepted by your REST API) is different: some services return some fields, others return other fields; some services return a whle country, some others only return or accept a country ID. So, design classes (DTOs) representing this communication model. And transform entities into the requested DTOs before returning these DTOs.

Comment: Yes I get this but I hoped the system has anything that can do this without any business logic. When I look on the Hotel table, there is column country_id. Doing this as u describe is not the best way imho. I do not need to use ORM for these cases, I have to retrieve object, then retrieve other one (that I alredy have solumn for in the first object) and connect them.